# TwitterCore sdk: buildToolsVersion is not specified

Tags: android

I'm trying to add `TwitterCore Kit` to my android app. I used this in my project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

and this in app level build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abhishek.cleartaxtask"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

When I sync gradle an error occurs `buildToolsVersion is not specified`. What am I doing wrong? How to add twitter sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove these lines from your `Build.Gradle` (Project:cleartaxtask). You are using the **Wrong Gradle** to apply the plugins.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Also move these lines in your `Build.Gradle` (Module:app).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

**EDIT 1**

> For CrashLytics Error add this to your Dependencies.

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Comment: only these 2 lines or all of them?

Comment: @crysis Only this two lines and then `Clean and Rebuild` your project it will work.

Comment: This error occured.  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
> Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

Answer (score 0):

For those who face same problem, add **maven** dependency at root(project) level build.gradle file.

```
 allprojects {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     } }
```